# Turn off videocard output on disconnecting monitor

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr, xorg.conf

My current setup is Arch, with Awesome WM and Xorg-server 1.17 (amd dependency). What I would like to automate is the following. When I disconnect an external monitor, for instance HDMI1, I have to manually run the following command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --off
```

Otherwise, the output stays active and my WM doesn't automatically remove the extra window space.

So my question is: Is there a way to automate the --off and --auto command of xrandr on respectively disconnection / connection of an external monitor and / or is there a configuration without the use of xrandr?